# How do I calculate this summation: $\sum_{n=1}^{k} 2^{2\times3^{n}}$

Tags: summation, summation-method

How do I calculate this summation?
$$\sum_{n=1}^{k} 2^{2\times3^{n}}$$

I couldn't find a way that works.

> Edit:

Fundamentally to Yves Daoust's comment is, can we write ?

$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{n=1}^{k} 2^{2\times3^{n}}}{2^{2\times3^{k}}}=1$$

Comment: = $\sum_{n=1}^{k} 4^3^n$

Comment: @TobyMak Not even close to the answer, it's a hint.

Comment: I'm sure there isn't any closed form for this.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson please, explain..Is it imposibble?

Comment: I think @GerryMyerson means that the formula might not be expressed just using elementary functions.

Comment: @TobyMak I hope I understood This is very important question for me.

Comment: What is there to explain? You are looking for a closed form. I'm telling you there isn't one.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Please don't be mad at me I am so sorry..

Comment: I'm not mad, I just don't know what you want me to explain.

Comment: @GerryMyerson TobyMak said, this is definitely possible.

Comment: Have it your way.

Comment: The first two comments by TobyMak are wrong.

Comment: @math: of course you can write that but my statement is much stronger: the ratio is extremely close to $1$. Please spend some effort checking this.

Comment: @Yves Daoust If I ask you, will you add the limit to the answer?

Comment: @Math: no, this has too little to do with the question and disregards the spirit of my answer.

Comment: @Yves Daoust , finally, Is this limit **absolutely true**?

Comment: @Math: your insistence becomes embarrassing.

Comment: @Yves Daoust I am simply grateful to you for your answer! I just wanted to ask **mathematically whether** this limit was correct. Thank you again. Your reply was very helpful to me.

Comment: @Math: my concern is that you still don't seem to consider/understand my answer.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I am so sorry. I gave you a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 2):

*This is probablky too long for a comment.*

As Gerry Myerson commented, I do not think that there is any closed form for this summation (even using special functions).

However, computing the first terms (up to $k=18$ for which $S_{18}\approx 1.769\times 10^{233250376}$  and plotting the results, it seems that $$\log (\log (S_k))=a + b\,k$$ could be a rather good approximation. A linear regression leads to $a=0.326638$ and $b=1.098610$. Using it for $k=10$, this would lead to $$\log (\log (S_{10}))=11.3128\implies S_{10}=1.185\times 10^{35551}$$ while the exact value is $\approx 1.097\times 10^{35551}$.

These are really very big numbers.

**Edit**

It seems to be nicer using $$\log_2 (\log_2 (S_k))=1+1.58496\, k$$

Comment: I wish, I wish I knew understanding something..

Comment: Claude, there is no need for deep research, the last term largely dominates. Your last constant is $\log_23$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust. My bad ! Shame on me but thanks ! Cheers

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: no shame. Now the true challenge is to let the OP understand, it seems. :)

Comment: @Yves Daoust I am trying for understand. :)

Answer (score 1):

With an excellent approximation,

$$\sum_{n=1}^k 2^{2\cdot3^n}\approx2^{2\cdot3^k}.$$

For example, already with $k=3$,

$$2^6+2^{18}+2^{54}=64+262144+18014398509481984\approx 18014398509481984.$$

The ratio is $1.000000000014\cdots$

Comment: I'm so confused. I am trying to understand.

Comment: @Math: the figures are in front of your eyes.

Comment: I understand that there is no other solution?

Comment: @Math: not at all. What makes you think that ??

Comment: Are you saying there are other solutions?

Comment: @math. Yes, but you didn't answer me.

Comment: I am sorry, english is not my mother tongue.I use google translate I did not understand you correctly.Please, write again what did you want?